# What does "reaching out about" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

https://www.changemakers.com/mentalhealth/entries/reaching-out-about-depression

What does "Reaching Out About Depression" mean?

Comment: What do you think it means? What does the dictionary say? Can you explain why you don't understand what the dictionary says?

Comment: I have no idea about the meaning. I couldn't find suitable meaning in dictionaries. I can understand what the dictionaries say. So would you please do me a favor? Inform me what can be used instead of "reaching out about"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "Reaching Out About Depression" mean?

The words "reach out" are a phrasal verb, defined here:
[Lexico "reach out"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/reach)

> 2 (North American) Seek to establish communication with someone, with the aim of offering or obtaining assistance or cooperation.
> *‘she was a great one for reaching out and helping people’*

A phrasal verb is one that includes a verb and another word. Phrasal verbs have a special meaning that may not be obvious from the words they are made from.

The words "about depression" are a preposition phrase that describes a reason for seeking or offering help.